# Is there a way I can update my samsung galaxy note 4.0.2 to 4.2.2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

Is there a way I can update it? 
Because i can't download many apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the OTA method, the recovery zip update method or Odin flashing method

For Odin:
Download the file from [here](http://www.droidopinions.com/how-to-update-galaxy-note-10-1-gt-n8000-to-4-4-2-kitkat-official/amp/) or [here](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-note-101/GT-N8000/) and flash it with Odin. Flash it as PDA or AP.

While booting, if stuck at the logo, simply boot into recovery and perform a factory reset.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61964/discussion-on-answer-by-esqmo-is-there-a-way-i-can-update-my-samsung-galaxy-not).

Comment: Thanks @MatthewRead This wasn't possible since I use mobile app. We have another long thread of comments on the other question. Please move it as well.